# User-fillable cell that gives error based on lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel newb here. I have a column in a sheet `WORKING` that needs to be able to take user input. The entries to this column should be present in another sheet `ENTRIES`. `ENTRIES` is also user filled. Each `ENTRIES` value will also be related to a "valid" column in the same row of the `ENTRIES` sheet.

I'd like some kind of error to appear in two cases:

1.) User inputs an entry to the column in `WORKING` and that entry is not present in `ENTRIES`.

2.) User inputs an entry to the column in `WORKING`, and that entry's corresponding "valid" is NO.

Is this possible? In the case of 2.) I suppose I could just create a lookup column in `WORKING` that showed validity, but that doesn't seem like the optimal solution as this sheet should be as automated as possible and an error message seems more clear than constantly checking another column.

Thanks.

EDIT:

After some consideration, I think it would actually be better for the `WORKING` column to be a drop down menu that excluded items that had already been selected or had a corresponding NO "valid" entry.

Comment: Yes, your best option would be drop-down list, achieved through data validation. [Here](http://www.excel-university.com/create-depdendent-drop-downs-conditional-data-validation/) you can find a good description, I think second part "Two tables approach" can help you to solve it. This probably will require your data in ENTRIES sheet to be sorted by "valid" column.